# If Variable name exceede 32 character in sas how to read them and how to read the UTC timestemp to check

Tags: sas

Q1.I  have a data set (excel file) that contains few variable names exceeding the 32 character limit of SAS. what to do to read those variables?

Q2.Same data set contains time in UTC format (2013-08-09T17:35:26.190). how to check them whether they are in sequential order from beginning to end?

Anybody can ans me would be a great help....i spent hours to figure out the solution. I am relatively new user of sas.

Thanks

Comment: Reasons for closing questions include, "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance." and "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."  What have you found so far in your hours figuring out the solution?  What didn't work about it?

Comment: You need to only ask one question per question.  Your first question is reasonable, the second is very poor as it does not have much detail and does not contain enough information to answer it effectively.  I recommend removing the second part, and starting a new question for that with much more detail.

Answer (score 1):

To refer a variable/field with a name exceeding 32 characters or otherwise breaking SAS naming rules, use single or double quotes and N, e.g.

```
'123long variable name 123456'N
```